# Normal map baking is not working, missig any details

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, normal-map

I have one high poly mesh and one low poly mesh

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have checked "selected to active" option but when i select first high poly object and then low poly object and click on bake, normal map is flat and without any details. I tryed the same method to create normal map on any other object with this high poly mesh and it works perfectly.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: maybe check the face orientation? or share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You need a UV map for your target mesh (Where the normal map have to be placed). Do you have a UV map created?

Comment: Thanks for help Christoph, i didn´t create UV map. Now It works fine. Thanks